# How to change the date in javascript having different timezones

Tags: javascript, php, date, datetime, timestamp-with-timezone

I am saving the date in database in unix-timestamp. I have set the timezone default to:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
```

but in javascript I am changing the timestamp in the following way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    if (originalData[i].SystemLogsUserAction.TimeStamp == "0") {
        records[i].TimeStamp = "";
    } else {
        records[i].TimeStamp = new Date(originalData[i].SystemLogsUserAction.TimeStamp * 1000);
    }
}
return records;
```

The above code change the time but it is not in timezone that I have mentioned.

Comment: If you are dealing with time zones, you may want to consider storing the UTC time and time zone offset.

Comment: I fully agree with Ron, try to store the times in UTC time, that´s easier when converting between them. And you can be sure that all times stored in the db have the same timezone.

Comment: I have stored the timezone in my core.php file like:-
 date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");

Comment: If you don't want to run into problems, design your app cleanly from the ground up. Let your server timezone be UTC. Configure your db to be UTC. Only store UTC timestamps (`zoned timestamp - timedelta = UTC timestamp`). Convert from UTC to user TZ when you display (`UTC timestamp + timedelta = zoned timestamp`). If you do it cleanly from the start, you'll be way less encline to run into problems.

Comment: I am not getting how you want me to do..

Answer (score 4):

Stolen shamelessly from: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329

```
// function to calculate local time
// in a different city
// given the city's UTC offset
function calcTime(city, offset) {

    // create Date object for current location
    d = new Date();

    // convert to msec
    // add local time zone offset
    // get UTC time in msec
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    // return time as a string
    return "The local time in " + city + " is " + nd.toLocaleString();

}
```

this function is useful to calculate time zone value by providing name of a city/country and offset value